# "Declaration or statement expected" (angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build C:\..)

Tags: angular

I was just starting to play around (Angular 2) and encountered this problem the thing is I already did trial and error and fixed the semi colons but nothing happened and this keeps on giving me error to my command line.

**app.component.ts**

[image]

**Command Line**

[image]

Comment: Please insert source code and error message as text

Comment: Hope my answer has helped you. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to export it as such:

```
export const hero:Hero = {
  ...
}
```

For more information I suggest you read about named exports https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export